# How to prevent function from using old function parameters

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to pass a function with parameters on click, and it works well if I submit the modal every time.

However, if I cancel it, and then click on the button again and submit, the function is called twice with wrong parameters

Steps to reproduce:

- Click Number 2 -> cancel -> click Number 1 -> Submit -> it will log both numbers instead of one

How do I make it "forget" about the previous parameters and use only the ones that are passed in that function?

```js
function showModal(body, onSubmit) {
  $("#number-modal").modal("show");
  $("#number-message").html("").html(body);
  $('[data-click="confirm"]').click(function () {
    $(this).off("click");
    onSubmit();
  });
}

function displayNumber(numb) {
  console.log("the number is", numb);
  $("#number-modal").modal("hide");
}

$('[data-number="one"]').click(function () {
  showModal("Hello number one!", function () {
    displayNumber("one");
  });
});

$('[data-number="two"]').click(function () {
  showModal("Hello number two!", function () {
    displayNumber("two");
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-number="one" class="btn btn-primary">Number 1</button>
<button data-number="two" class="btn btn-primary">Number 2</button>

<div class="modal fade"
     id="number-modal"
     tabindex="-1"
     data-backdrop="static"
     data-keyboard="false"
     role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-info" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Number Modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="number-message"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer info-modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" data-click="cancel">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-click="confirm">Confirm</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The issue isn't "old parameters", it's the fact that each event handler you add *supplements* the set of event handlers already present. The `.click()` method does not remove existing handlers, in other words.

Comment: Is there a way to remove existing handlers?

Comment: In general I would advise that adding and removing event handlers is a really clumsy way to manage behavioral response to events. It'd be much better to maintain contextual data, either as attributes in the DOM or in some JavaScript closure or objects or whatever, and conditionally respond in straight JavaScript code.

Comment: You have numerous options - you're already using `.off` - so could stick with that: `$('[data-click="confirm"]').off("click").on("click", function`...  if you're going to do `click(()=>off` then use `.one` (but that's not what you want, just what you're doing here).

Answer (score 0):

You generally should never add new event handlers *inside an event handler*, because event handlers stack.

There is no magic remembering old values, there are only more and more event handlers running every time you do this. So don't. Set up event handlers *once*.

```js
function showModal(body, target) {
  $('#number-modal').modal('show').data('target', target);
  $('#number-message').html(body);
}
function onSubmit() {
  $('#number-modal').modal('hide');
  alert('You submitted the form to '+ $('#number-modal').data('target'));
}

$(document).on('click', '[data-number="one"]', function () {
  showModal('Hello number one!', 'target 1');
});

$(document).on('click', '[data-number="two"]', function () {
  showModal('Hello number two!', 'target 2');
});

$(document).on('click', '[data-click="confirm"]', onSubmit);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-number="one" class="btn btn-primary">Number 1</button>
<button data-number="two" class="btn btn-primary">Number 2</button>

<div class="modal fade"
     id="number-modal"
     tabindex="-1"
     data-backdrop="static"
     data-keyboard="false"
     role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-info" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Number Modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="number-message"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer info-modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" data-click="cancel">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-click="confirm">Confirm</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. If I want to submit the form to different endpoints, based on the button that triggered the modal, how do I pass that?

Comment: @Tom Oh, that was the intention. You could use a the modal's `.data()` to transport this information, see updated answer.